# Watch and see usage

Tags: word-usage

When should be used see and when watch? For example: if you look at a mirror you see you or you watch you? The same as if a camera is recording you an it appears in a tv in real-time, are you seeing you or watching you?

Comment: ELL http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53678/what-is-different-between-look-see-and-watch

Comment: You **see yourself** in a mirror. You're just standing there; there's nothing happening—nothing to watch. Of course you could also **inspect, appraise, observe,** or **admire** (etc) yourself.  In the video camera you do see yourself, but almost all of us are drawn to continue to **watch** our _movement_, perhaps because it is reversed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to acknowledge that something appears before your eyes use *to see*. If you want to say that you're distributing your attention over a certain period of time on *seeing* something, then use *watch.* Sometimes you would want to use *observe* when you're watching something to form a conclusion.

- I see a man falling. (means that it appears before your eyes)
- I watch a man falling. (means that you distribute your attention over a certain period of time looking at that person falling)
- I observe a man falling. (meaning that you want to form a conclusion from the different things you see while watching the man falling)